# Drag and Drop solution in java script

Tags: javascript, jointjs

In JavaScript, we want implementation where we will have some dragable elements as input and some drop area(like, Inout , proccessing and output area) where we can drag and drop respective elements in respective area and that should be linked automatically. Is there any solution available in java script using some library like JointJS.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best light-weight solutions for Drag and Drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097600/what-are-the-best-light-weight-solutions-for-drag-and-drop)

Comment: html 5 has a good implementation of drag and drop in w3schools tutorial site  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp    For linking there are many frameworks including jointjs, i have found joint js to be good if you like to dig through their code, tutorial is not extensive

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below solution.

If your application is going to be JS heavy, I recommend using a javascript library. I prefer jquery, but there are many more libraries for doing this.

The functionality you are looking for is available in the jQueryUI project as a widget `http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/`

Some people might find it distasteful that I'm recommending a framework, but it will get the job done quicker for you.

Have a look at this example on the files needed to setup a demo `http://jsbin.com/ejolo6`